# How to disable evaluation of static_asserts in PC-lint

Tags: c++, static-assert, pc-lint

I am using C++'s static_assert feature to check things at compile time which usually should pass, e.g:

```
static_assert( SOME_CONSTANT < 1000u, "..." );
```

Running PC-lint (version 9.00k) on that code emits note 948: "Operator '<' always evaluates to True", which is kind of pointless for static_asserts.

I know I can either append a `//lint !e948` to every static_assert (which is what I do for now) or disable 948 globally, but that would also hide legitimate errors everywhere else.

Is it possible to tell PC-lint to not evaluate/check expressions in static_asserts?

Comment: That’s quite simply a bug. [Can you submit a bug report to the developers?](http://www.gimpel.com/html/support.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You can teach PC-Lint to handle static_assert() the same way it handles assert(). Just add the following lines to your code:

```c++
#ifdef _lint
//lint -function(__assert, static_assert)
void static_assert(bool, const char*);
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I added the following line to my .lnt config file to solve this issue.

`-dstatic_assert()=   // ignore keyword static_assert and following parenthetical`